# how to extract the value from multiple columns in a specific order

Tags: r

I have this dataset that contains variables from three previous years.

```
data <- read.table(text="
 a        2015  2016  2017  
 1        100    100   100
 2        1000    5    NA
 3       10000    NA   NA", header=TRUE)
```

I would like to create a new column in my data which contains the value from the most recent year. The order is 2017 ->2016 ->2015.

```
output <- read.table(text="
 a        2015  2016  2017  recent
 1        100    100   100   100
 2        1000    5    NA     5
 3       10000    NA   NA     10000", header=TRUE)
```

I know that I can use "if" command to achieve it, but I am wondering if there is a quick and simple way to do it. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple base R solution. This assumes that the years are sorted from left-right.

```
data$recent <- apply(data, 1, function(x) tail(na.omit(x), 1))

  a X2015 X2016 X2017 recent
1 1   100   100   100    100
2 2  1000     5    NA      5
3 3 10000    NA    NA  10000
```